# My Bluemix container is not accessing Mongodb service bind to it

Tags: mongodb, containers, ibm-cloud

I have created a docker container image on my Bluemix private registry. My docker image (Dockerfile) contains the following things-

```
FROM registry.ng.bluemix.net/ibmliberty  
RUN rm -rf /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/server.xml 
ADD server.xml /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/server.xml  
RUN rm -rf /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/workarea  
ADD ./build/libs/*.war /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/apps  
ENV LISCENSE accept
```

I also created a mongoDB service to attach with my container.

When I am done with creating my container and binding it with the mongoDB service, then I hit containers (IP/URL). My application is running but not connecting to the database. In container logs I am getting socketTimeout exception.
logs-

```
0[err]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
[err] com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting
for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}.
Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=50.23.230.160:1
0082, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenExce
ption: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.SocketTimeoutException: co
nnect timed out}}]
```

I have included the db parameter in my server.xml, and also tried different approaches to give the db parameter while creating the container by specifying Environment variable. These parameters contain almost all information like host,port,db,uname,pwd.

After trying lots of approaches in different ways, I am not able to find what I am doing wrong. Please help me to resolve this issue.